# how to only keep compressed sparse row indices that are in a list

Tags: python, sparse-matrix

say I have an adjacency matrix in csr format:

```
row = np.array([0, 0, 1, 3, 2, 2,3,4,4])
col = np.array([0, 4, 2, 2, 3, 1,4,0,3])
data = np.array([1]*len(row))
X= sp.csr_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(5, 5))

print(X)
  (0, 0)    1
  (0, 4)    1
  (1, 2)    1
  (2, 1)    1
  (2, 3)    1
  (3, 2)    1
  (3, 4)    1
  (4, 0)    1
  (4, 3)    1

print(X.todense())
[[1 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0]
 [0 0 1 0 1]
 [1 0 0 1 0]]
```

i have a list of the nodes i want to keep, say nodes 1 and 2 `keep = [1,2]`
how would i keep all the indices in X that are in the list "keep" ?
For example, I want to end up with all indices whose row or col is in the list keep:

```
  (1, 2)    1
  (2, 1)    1
  (2, 3)    1
  (3, 2)    1
```

`X[keep]` only returns the rows 1,2:

```
print(X[keep].todense())
[[0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0]]
```

but i can see that node 2, interacts with nodes 1 and nodes 3; therefore, i want to return an adjacency matrix that reflects the bi-directional connections of the subset adjacency matrix:

```
[[0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0*]
```

The 0* represents the fact that because i'm only interested in node 1 (only interacts with node 2) and node 2 (interacts with nodes 1 and 3), then despite in the original matrix we observe node 3 interacting with nodes 2 and 4, node 4 isn't in the list to keep so we ignore it. Hence want to end up with something like:

```
  (1, 2)    1
  (2, 1)    1
  (2, 3)    1
  (3, 2)    1
```

...I realize, after the edits to this question to try to clarify what i'm trying to do, it may not be so simple a solution, but i am still unsure on how to approach it.

Answer (score 0):

Your indices are stored in:

```
ix = X.nonzero()
```

You can create a boolean to subset your indices:

```
inkeep = np.isin(ix[0],keep) | np.isin(ix[1],keep)
```

Then get something like this:

```
np.array(ix)[:,inkeep].T

array([[1, 2],
   [2, 1],
   [2, 3],
   [3, 2]], dtype=int32)
```

However if you want to return the sparse matrix containing the intersection of what you want, i.e, rows that are 1,2 **and** cols that are 1,2, it will be something like:

```
X[1:3,1:3]
```

or:

```
X[keep,:][:,keep]
```

Comment: how would i keep it as a sparse csr matrix? i realized after that my mwe wasn't entirely accurate of what i'm working with, but i essentially am trying to end up with a subset of an original symmetric/bi-directional adjacency matrix. so from my original adjacency, i'm only selecting a few nodes; and in the subset, i want it to still be symmetric.. if that makes sense?

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't. so if you already know the rows you want, isn't it a matter of subsetting the matrix according to that?

Comment: hmm, i think i'm confused with the sparse matrix.. i don't normally work with them but my dataset is large so i was given my dataset as a compressed csr. i know the rows i'm trying to keep, so i tried the X[keep], but it doesn't return a symmetric matrix

Comment: just wanted to comment that i edited my original post to better represent a symmetric sparse matrix instead. your answer did reflect what i had posted, which was ``` row = np.array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2,3,3,4,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,8,9])
col = np.array([0, 4, 3, 2, 3, 1,1,4,2,3,1,4,3,2,2,3,1,4])
data = np.array([1]*len(row))
X= sp.csr_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(10, 5))```

Comment: ok i think your edited post does not reflect what you want. if it is an adjacency matrix, and you want selected indices, then you need to extract, the same rows and columns

Comment: yes, so how can i do that? X[keep] returns all the rows i'd like to keep, but X[keep,keep] doesn't specify the columns.. sorry, i'm new to python as well

Comment: X[keep,keep] returns you X[1,1] and X[2,2], see edited post

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried to figure out what you are trying to do.  But some background on sparse matrices may be in order.

First from your data lets make a `coo` format:

```
In [1]: from scipy import sparse as sp
In [2]: row = np.array([0, 0, 1, 3, 2, 2,3,4,4])
   ...: col = np.array([0, 4, 2, 2, 3, 1,4,0,3])
   ...: data = np.array([1]*len(row))
   ...: X= sp.coo_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(5, 5))
   ...: 
In [3]: X
Out[3]: 
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 9 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [4]: X.A
Out[4]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]])
In [5]: X.row,X.col
Out[5]: 
(array([0, 0, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4], dtype=int32),
 array([0, 4, 2, 2, 3, 1, 4, 0, 3], dtype=int32))
```

In `coo`, the `row,col,data` attributes are like what you provided, in fact they may be the same arrays (if not a copy).

The `csr` format is processed - sorted, and summed if there are duplicates.  The row/col have been changed, so the layout isn't a obvious.

```
In [6]: Xr = X.tocsr()
In [7]: Xr.indptr
Out[7]: array([0, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9], dtype=int32)
In [8]: Xr.indices
Out[8]: array([0, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 0, 3], dtype=int32)
```

`csr` implements most of the sparse math.  It also implements indexing; coo does not implement indexing. In fact in the more general cases `csr` indexing is implemented via matrix multiplication.  Sparse matrices were originally developed for large linear algebra problems, such as finite different and finite element code.  I haven't done anything with `scipy.sparse.csgraph`.

Where possible `csr` indexing tries to behave like the corresponding dense indexing

```
In [9]: keep=[1,2]
In [10]: Xr[keep]
Out[10]: 
<2x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [11]: Xr.A[keep]
Out[11]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]])
```

This just selects two rows from the matrix/array.

The `nonzero` method of `X` (or `Xr`) should give the same arrays that you get from a dense array.  Again it's essentially the `row/col` attributes of `coo`.

```
In [14]: X.nonzero()
Out[14]: 
(array([0, 0, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4], dtype=int32),
 array([0, 4, 2, 2, 3, 1, 4, 0, 3], dtype=int32))
In [15]: np.nonzero(X.A)
Out[15]: (array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]), array([0, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 0, 3]))
```

It be better to figure out what you are doing with a regular numpy array, e.g. `X.A`.  Once that's working, then you might be able to work directly with the sparse matrices and their attributes.